# Get user thanks count that is given by other users

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to build forum, but I need help about building MySQL query.
So my question - What MySQL query build should be to get user thanks count that is given by other users?

```
   f_posts (table)
   Columns:
   - id
   - user_id (post author)

   f_thanks (table)
   Columns:
   - user_id (who give thanks)
   - post_id
```

I tried to build query with FlySpeed SQL query builder and it looks:

```
SELECT p.id, p.user_id, k.id, k.post_id
FROM f_thanks k
LEFT JOIN f_posts p ON p.id = k.post_id 
WHERE p.user_id = 15
```

[Result](http://prntscr.com/7nhhdt) (5 rows)
But it's not correct, because I have more than 5 thanks (should be atleast 10...)

```
SELECT count(*) FROM f_thanks WHERE user_id = 15
```

Result is 4 rows and it's correct, because I gave 4 thanks to other users.

(I've translated them: kiitused = thanks; postitused = posts; Estonian-English)

But I need to get user thanks count that is given by other users.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `left join`.  Then your `where` clause is turning it into an `inner join`, because of the `NULL` values produced by the `left join`.

The solution is to move the condition to the `on` clause:

```
SELECT p.id, p.user_id, k.id, k.post_id
FROM f_thanks k LEFT JOIN
     f_posts p
     ON p.id = k.post_id AND
        p.user_id = 15;
```

When using `left join`, always put conditions on the second table into the `on` clause.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried this query and it seems that result is still incorrect.
http://prntscr.com/7nht98
Result is only 5 rows. One my post have atleast 6 thanks.

Comment: @Typhome . . . This query should not lose any rows.  Can you set up a SQL Fiddle with a sample of the data?

Comment: I wonder if this is correct link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/42d93/1/0
I've inserted 5 thanks for user ID 15 posts, but SQL fiddle result is 8 rows.

Comment: What do you want the query to return?  Why isn't an inner join sufficient?